# Is there a relation between the cohomology ring of a blowup with the base scheme and blowup locus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory, blowup

Let
$$
Y \subset X
$$
be a codimension 2 or greater smooth subvariety of a smooth projective variety $X$. Is there a relation between the cohomology of the blowup $Bl_Y(X)$ and the cohomology rings of $X,Y$?

Comment: There is a kind of Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence associated to the "cover" of $X$ by $Y$ and $Bl_Y(X)$. This gives : $$...\longrightarrow H^n(X)\longrightarrow H^n(Y)\oplus H^n(Bl_Y(X))\longrightarrow H^n(E)\longrightarrow H^{n+1}(X)\longrightarrow ...$$ where $E$ is the exceptional divisor (it also works if $Y$ is not smooth). The maps are the usual pullback in cohomology.

Comment: Cool, and I can determine the cohomology of $E$ using a spectral sequence!

Comment: @Roland Do you know if this sequence is a sequence of hodge structures?

Comment: Yes it is, only the boundary require some works, but in fact it is even a sequence of motives.

Comment: By the way, the cohomology of $E$ is a free $H^*(Y)$-module (in case $Y$ is smooth).

Comment: @Roland Is the algebra structure $H^*(Y)\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{k+1})$ where $k+1$ is the rank of the normal bundle?

Comment: No the algebra structure is $H^*(Y)[\zeta]/(\zeta^{k+1}+c_1\zeta^k+c_2\zeta^{k-1}+...+c_{k+1})$ where $c_1,...,c_{k+1}$ are the Chern classes of the normal bundle.

Comment: Oh right, because of the projective bundle formula.

Comment: By the way, I should have said that earlier, but if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, the boundary is zero since then it is a map between Hodge structure of different weights. You then have an isomorphism $H^n(Bl_Y(X))\oplus H^n(Y)=H^n(X)\oplus H^n(E)$.

Comment: @Roland This is very nice consider the motivic interpretation that $H^n(Bl_Y(X)) = H^n(X)\oplus H^n(E) \ominus H^n(Y)$!